# react phone number validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, joi

I am using [joi-phone-numbe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-phone-number)r library for phone number validation.

This is sample code for react am trying

```
import Joi from 'joi';
import cNumber from 'joi-phone-number';
const myJoi = Joi.extend(cNumber);

schema = {
        phone: myJoi.string().phoneNumber({defaultCountry: 'US',format: 'international'})
}
```

The problem is it validates only first two digits after that it shows the number is correct

```
Example
09 Invalid
999 Valid
```

So how am supposing to use this with react. Mine goal is here to check country code too with valid phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but can you try this?

```
import simpleJoi from "joi";
const Joi = simpleJoi.extend(require("joi-phone-number"));

schema = {
  phone: Joi.string().phoneNumber({defaultCountry: 'US',format:'international'})
}
```